# PHP SQL Form Insert Creation

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I am trying to create a simple form that will insert the given data received by my HTML form, into my SQL table named 'Vendors', however I am struggling to work with its functionality.

There are 7 text fields that I am wanting to add to my Vendors table, and these are so named:

- vendorName
- addressL1 (Line 1)
- addressL2
- postcode
- email
- telephone
- description

The HTML for this form can be found below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="" method="post">
   <ul class="form-style-1">

     <li>
       <label style="color:#4D4D4D;" >Vendor Name <span class="required">*
       </span></label>
       <center> <input type="text" name="vendorName" class="field-long" 
       required="required" placeholder="Vendor Name" /> </center>
     </li>  

     <li>
      <label style="color:#4D4D4D;">Vendor Address <span class="required">*
      </span></label>
      <center> <input type="text" name="addressL1" required="required" 
      class="field-long" placeholder="Address Line 1" /> </center>
      </br>     
      <center> <input type="text" name="addressL2" required="required" 
      class="field-long" placeholder="Address Line 2" /> </center>
      </br>
      <center> <input type="text" name="postcode" required="required" 
      class="field-short" placeholder="Postcode" /> </center>       
    </li>

    <li>
      <label style="color:#4D4D4D;">Vendor Contact Details <span 
      class="required">*</span></label>
      <center> <input type="text" name="email" required="required" 
      class="field-long" placeholder="Email Address" /> </center>
      </br>
      <center> <input type="text" name="telephone" required="required" 
      class="field-long" placeholder="Phone Number" /> </center>
      </select>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label style="color:#4D4D4D;">Vendor Description </label>
      <center> <textarea name="description" id="field5" class="field-long 
      field-textarea" placeholder="Description"></textarea> </center>
    </li>

    <li>
      <center> <input type="submit" class="AddButton" value="POST"></input> 
      </center>
    </li>

    </ul>
    </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And the PHP I have used is:

```
 <?php      
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
        $server = "";
        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo);
        if (!$conn)
        {
            die("Connection failed");
        }

        $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')           
        {
            $VendorName = $_POST['vendorName'];
            $AddressLine1 = $_POST['addressL1'];
            $AddressLine2 = $_POST['addressL2'];
            $Postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
            $VendorEmail = $_POST['email'];
            $VendorNumber = $_POST['telephone'];
            $VendorDes = $_POST['description'];
            $time = time();
            $timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);

            $describeQuery = ("INSERT INTO Vendors (VendorName, VendorAL1, 
            VendorAL2, VendorPost, VendorEmail, VendorNumber, VendorDes, 
            Added) 
            VALUES ('".$VendorName."', '".$AddressLine1."', 
                            '".$AddressLine2."', '".$Postcode."', 
                            '".$VendorEmail."', '".$VendorNumber."', 
                            '".$VendorDes."', '".$timestamp."')");
            $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $describeQuery);

            if(sqlsrv_query($conn, $describeQuery))
            {
                $alert = "Vendor Successfully Added";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$alert');
                </script>";
            }

            else
            {               
                echo 'Information not inserted';
            }   
        }               

        sqlsrv_close($conn);        
  ?>
```

Each time I submit the form, it goes straight to the 'Information not inserted' ELSE statement and doesn't import the data into my database.

I have removed my server name and database name for precautionary reasons, however I can assure you they are correct as I have worked on a previous project and used the same method of connecting.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, and if there are any formatting mistakes, apologies in advance, I am not an avid user of stack overflow.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do when using the [low-level SQL server driver](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using. **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: Consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. With those you have patterns you could follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts. What you have here is a confused stew of concerns, with HTML, PHP, and SQL all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and many spots in between.

Comment: This is not a project I plan on publishing or preparing for real world use. There are many examples online similar to mine on lower level PHP tutorial websites which is why I came here for guidance on where I went wrong, not how my programming style could be improved...

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is to stop using "lower level PHP tutorial websites" because most of them are pure poison in terms of promoting bad habits and are often filled with nothing but out-dated junk. A good framework keeps evolving and improving. YouTube tutorials, if anything, have degraded considerably over the last ten years. If you want to actually learn PHP and not just smash around with bits of code, use a framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use Mysqli Please, I have updated the script.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "INSERT INTO Vendors (VendorName, VendorAL1, 
            VendorAL2, VendorPost, VendorEmail, VendorNumber, VendorDes, 
            Added) 
VALUES ($VendorName, $AddressLine1, $AddressLine2,$Postcode,$VendorEmail,$VendorNumber,$VendorDes,$timestamp)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

Comment: This not only fixes absolutely nothing, it switches to the wrong database. You can't access a SQL Server instance with `mysqli`. That's exclusively for MySQL-type servers.

Comment: I have just given the example as he was promoting wrong way, I have used mysqli

Comment: Everything about this code is wrong. It has absolutely no hope of working even *if* they were using MySQL, which they're not. Please, take a moment to consider what you're suggesting here because it makes no sense. You can't just stuff values like that in your query and expect it to work.

Comment: I have perfectly checked and posted it :)

Comment: Oh, the old "it works on my machine" answer. So helpful.

Comment: As u wish then bro :)

Comment: When someone asks a SQL Server question **answer with SQL Server code**.

Comment: @tadman Just for reference , hope so you got it what I have solved https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: I should have suspected you were another victim of w3schools.